# iotop shows negative values for some metrics

Tags: linux, io, bugs, metric

To gather some metrics, cumulative :

> iotop -P -a

On one server (Linux 2.6.18-348.6.1.el5, centos 5.9) iotop (iotop 0.4.3) shows :

> ```
> 5 be/7 root          0.00 B      0.00 B -125056859448.21 %  0.20 % [ksoftirqd/1]
>
> 6 rt/3 root          0.00 B      0.00 B -574104403438.82 %  0.00 % [migration/2]
> ```

migration slowly falls and about 60 seconds later it will be out of the realtime output screen.

ksoftirq remains listed with this weird negative 'SWAPIN %'.

Question : is this value  a trivial bug of iotop or can it outline a real problem ?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server??

Comment: it isn't possible during working hours, the restart will be next saturday night

Comment: I think you should try htop.It might help you find the bug.